# Return all possible combinations of two lists

Tags: python, list, class, oop, combinations

I've tried to return all the possible combinations of two given lists using **class** the combination will have to consist of one element from each list. I can do until the length of the second list is 1. But after increasing the length, I don't get the expected output.

*as an example the code is*

```
class IceCreamMachine:

    def __init__(self, ingredients, toppings):
        self.ingredients = ingredients
        self.toppings = toppings
        
    def scoops(self):
        IceCreamList = []
        for i in range(len(self.ingredients)):
            IceCreamList.append([self.ingredients[i], self.toppings[i%len(self.toppings)]])
        
        return IceCreamList
        
machine = IceCreamMachine(["vanilla", "chocolate"], ["chocolate sauce"])

print(machine.scoops())
```

it returns the expected output which is **[['vanilla', 'chocolate sauce'], ['chocolate', 'chocolate sauce']]** but whenever I tend to increase the element of the second list it shows an incorrect answer.
Can anyone suggest me how to solve the problem?

Comment: Use `itertools.product`.

Comment: suppose you have list in `d = [["vanilla", "chocolate"], ["chocolate sauce"]]` you can use itertools like @chepner said `print(list(product(*d)))` this will give you `[('vanilla', 'chocolate sauce'), ('chocolate', 'chocolate sauce')]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `itertools.product`

```
import itertools

class IceCreamMachine:
    def __init__(self, ingredients, toppings):
        self.ingredients = ingredients
        self.toppings = toppings
        
    def scoops(self):
      return list(itertools.product(self.ingredients,self.toppings))
        
machine = IceCreamMachine(["vanilla", "chocolate"], ["chocolate sauce","banana sauce"])
print(machine.scoops())
```

output

```
[('vanilla', 'chocolate sauce'), ('vanilla', 'banana sauce'), ('chocolate', 'chocolate sauce'), ('chocolate', 'banana sauce')]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be done by using two for-loop:

```
def scoops(self):
    IceCreamList = []
    for i in range(len(self.ingredients)):
        for j in range(len(self.toppings)):
            IceCreamList.append([self.ingredients[i], self.toppings[j]])
    
    return IceCreamList
```

use "for [variable] in [list]" can make the code looks simpler

```
def scoops(self):
    IceCreamList = []
    for i in self.ingredients:
        for j in self.toppings:
            IceCreamList.append([i,j])
    
    return IceCreamList
```

if you want to have the combination with more than one option, the code will be more complicated then this...